# JBoss AS 6.1 EJB3 Pool never bigger than 50

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I'm currently doing load tests on a old JBoss AS 6.1.
But I have the problem that the EJB3 pool seems to be limited to 50.

In the JMX Console is see :

CreateCount 50
CurrentSize 50
RemoveCount 0
MaxSize     50

InvocationStatistics 
concurrentCalls='48' method name='applyRegulator' count='1902' minTime='108' maxTime='5825' totalTime='1874001'

What's strange is that I can add the @Pool annotation or change the pool size in ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml but it still limits at 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EJB 3 connector is configured in ejb3-connectors-jboss-beans.xml, not remoting-jboss-beans.xml or any other file!

socket://${hostforurl}:${port}?timeout=300000&maxPoolSize=3000&clientMaxPoolSize=500

Source: https://developer.jboss.org/message/615825#615825

Answer (score 0):

Have you increased the number of JMS sessions available?

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue="30")
```

If you instance pool is not being filled, then you are most likely running out of JMS sessions.

Comment: It's not an MDB. It's a Stateless Session Bean.